# What is this "chat with an expert" message I keep seeing?

Tags: support

The pass couple of days I see this little popup on the side of questions that says "Chat with an expert":

[image]

At first I thought it was a functionality in which you can directly go into a chatroom generated specifically for that question but when i clicked on it I get this...

[image]

What the heck is this?

Answer (score 3):

It's an April Fools joke. You can chat with an "expert" (a bot) if you'd like, or just dismiss it permanently. See [What is "chat with an expert"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert) on meta.SO.