# Save me from "trivial answer converted to comment" please!

Tags: bug, feature-request

It just took me three tries to answer [this question](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1693/what-is-this-chat-with-an-expert-message-i-keep-seeing). The first two, my answer was [automatically converted into a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/133299). While I appreciate what this feature is trying to do, it was *really* aggravating. I felt like I had to jump through hoops just to post an answer, and maybe even worse, the site involuntarily made me do something I knew was bad. My first two tries:

> April Fools joke. See [What is "chat with an expert"?][1] on meta.SO. [1]: [link url]
>
> It's an April Fools joke from the site. See [What is "chat with an expert"?][1] on meta.SO. [1]: [link url]

My absolute biggest complaint is that it's converted to a comment immediately, without any chance to edit it. I then have to copy and paste it back, fix the markup a little, delete my comment, and try again.

To make a specific feature request, I think the nicest thing would be to give me the choice: convert to comment ("this looks trivial, want to post it as a comment?") or don't post ("write a better answer"). Failing that, you could just refuse to let me post the answer, keeping the cooldown period, with an explanation.

If you think these will encourage people gaming the system - instead of letting it just stay as a comment, lengthening an answer until it gets through - you could keep the old behavior for low-rep users. (Or I suppose you could have Community flag answers as low quality if they were submitted like this; I can't imagine it's so high-volume that it'd clog the flag queue.)

Again, I understand encouraging real answers. But I was trying to write one, and the effect of this mechanism was to make that *harder* and discourage me, the exact opposite of the goal.

Edit/bump: I just ran into this again, and given that the site also enforces a 60 second cooldown on trying to answer again, I deem this a bug. I have a ton of reputation, full privileges, I'm a mod, and I have to wait 60 seconds to fix up my too-short answer. Feel free to block me from submitting (as with "Body must be at least 30 characters"), but don't lock me out for 60 seconds.

Comment: I very much agree..  Especially for users with say 1k reputation....   why have this at all?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I think it does have a real purpose - an answer that's essentially just a link to another question (as mine was) is in general not useful. (And I think that's what it's detecting.)

Comment: Yeah, well you cannot close as dup to a cross-site meta.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Which is why it was right to force me to include some actual information in my answer by extending it a little. We want the information here too, as long as someone asked. (Conveniently enough, [this was covered here a week ago](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/does-everything-on-meta-stackoverflow-com-apply-to-seasoned-advice?cb=1#comment4831_1683).) So I'm fine with that standard being applied even to a mod; I just want it to help me, not hurt me.

Comment: For those who have no idea what this about (like me), [here is the original question about this feature on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/141911).